# Material-UI: Cannot delete input value because of losing focus inside DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, input, datagrid, material-ui, focus

I'm trying to use Material-UI `DataGrid`. I want to use a button inside one of the columns of the table. This button has to be a Modal with form inside. When I did it I noticed that I can typing in form inputs, but I can't delete with delete key and backspace, because focus lost and how I understood it focus was on the table, but not on the modal input. Using default examples from documentation I did a simple example on CodeSandbox. Input from there has the same behavior.

PS. Try to type something and backspace then. Do you have any idea?

[image: Edit https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rselz]

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved by calling `stopPropagation()` on `keydown` event in your `TextField`. It prevents the `DataGrid` from intercepting your `keydown` event and do its own thing:

```js
renderCell: () => <TextField onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66824289/losing-focus-and-unexpected-behaviour-input-inside-datagrid-material-ui]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, though I decided to take my modal window outside the table and leave only the button in the table.