# DataGrid material-ui disable backspace and delete key in column

Tags: datagrid, material-ui

Please someone know how disable backspace and delete key in column when use DataGrid with material-ui ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable delete key in `DataGrid`?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/demo/ click on a cell and press "delete" or "backspace", the content will be deleted, it will trigger the desired action for me. I need to decipher it completely.

Comment: When I have an edit button in the DataGrid, the focus in the table in the cell remains, the Dialog with the form opens, I print a backspace to delete the data in the input in dialog, the component Dialog is redrawn.

Comment: I use renderCell for btn, when I click on this button (component with dialog), I am left with the function linked to Delete Key, when I press the delete key, the rows in the table are rendered again. It does mischief. It did the same problems after clicking, I solved it disableClickEventBubbling: false, but I can't deactivate the Delete Key anywhere. :-/

Comment: You can attach a click handler and call `e.stopPropagation()` like in my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832645/9449426)

Comment: Thank you lot off!  `<Dialog onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>` works! But would like to disableClickDeleteKey. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Dialog onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
```